# May comments be used to answer old unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, moderation, unanswered-questions

There are many comments that solve the problem, but the question has no answer. If the comment could make a answer is it ok to make an answer out of it to get rid of old unanswered questions?

[A heat resistant connection between power supply and a resistive wire circuit (heat grid)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/382782/a-heat-resistant-connection-between-power-supply-and-a-resistive-wire-circuit-h)

Comment: related meta question, if not duplicate: [How to handle answers in comments?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6728/7036) and [Why do people answer in comments?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5803/7036)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! If people choose to write answers in comments, that's on them. There's no reason for you not to put the same information into an actual answer.

Comment: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6918/which-moderator-to-listen-to