# Which moderator to listen to?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I asked: [May comments be used to answer old unanswered questions?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/may-comments-be-used-to-answer-old-unanswered-questions)

One moderator says yes and the another moderator said no on the old questions  answered this way. Should I listen to the moderator with a higher rep.?

Side Question? Is it better to have a half answer then no answer to lower unanswered questions?

Comment: Remember, there are no down votes on comments. For whatever reason, the people writing those comments deliberately did not answer the question. It may be that the OP replied with "this solved my problem", or the comment could be completely wrong. *You* are taking responsibility for the quality and correctness of the answer, not the original commenter.

Comment: @W5VO I don't understand how doing this is wrong?

Comment: What we were expecting was something along the lines of these questions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226231/avr-gcc-float-macro-error https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368239/latch-circuit-requiring-the-button-to-be-pressed-6-times/368269#368269 where the answer was left in the comments, and then *turned into* an answer. What *you* did was blindly copy the comments section into the answer field on "unanswered" questions.

Comment: @W5VO I also grammar corrected it. I will not copy and past like this but the other mod did say yes.

Comment: @Muze Dave said yes to your question on meta which was "May comments be used to answer old unanswered questions?". "Yes" is a reasonable answer to a generic question like this. Now he certainly didn't have a thorough look at the specific comment you were planning to reuse, and if he did, he certainly couldn't imagine you would copypaste it as is, given the poor quality of this comment. You seem to be interpreting way too much things about Dave's answer. It certainly wasn't a green light to turn any random comment into an answer.

Comment: I would suggest making the answers community wiki if you're just trying to be a good netizen and not purely trying to acquire rep.

Comment: On odd numbered days I listen to Nick, on even numbered days I go with Dave

Comment: Funny that a user who is genuinely trying to learn how to use SE is downvoted for asking how to use SE in meta.

Comment: @slm community wiki is basically depreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answers are old comments repeated *verbatim*.  I'll show these answers here for folks who don't have the 10k visibility yet.

from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/430612/7036) [since it provides context for this meta, I'm not going to delete that just yet] :

> The voltage across each depends on how much current each needs to
>   operate. If one has a resistance equivalent to 10 Ohms and the other a
>   resistance equivalent to 100Ohms then you will have a voltage divider
>   such that there is 10 times more voltage across the larger resistance.
>   Just use a 5V regulator to power both devices. – JRE Jan 7 '17 at 8:51
>
> Your margins are too small if the absolute maximum rating of a
>   component is 5V then supplying it with 5V is asking for trouble. Any
>   supply deviation (spikes, noise) can result in failure. Then we get
>   into how the voltage is shared between the components to answer that
>   we need to know what they are and how they are being operated. – RoyC
>   Jan 7 '17 at 10:28
>
> Use two TL431 shunt regulators. One in parallel with each element.
>
> These should be made an answer.
>   [May comments be used to answer old unanswered questions?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/may-comments-be-used-to-answer-old-unanswered-questions)

from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/430618/7036):

> If the speed control works somewhat, the basic design and assembly is
>   probably OK, but there is a problem with connections and/or noise.
>   Lack of isolation between the mains and the control circuitry is
>   always a risk. The main current path for the motor current shown as
>   two of 8 ground symbols is also suspect. – Charles Cowie Dec 15 '16 at
>   12:28
>
> Should be an answer.
>   [May comments be used to answer old unanswered questions?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/may-comments-be-used-to-answer-old-unanswered-questions)

from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/430574/7036):

> Elliott, I am too young to relate with incandescent light bulbs. Yes,
>   I guess that's a good example of circuits at different temperatures!
>   No light emission required tho, just softening metal plates for clay
>   mold covering. Yes indeed Uwe, it would be another DIY. Thanks, Peter
>   I've found this question
>   electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350145/… that has "use copper
>   attached to steel bonded to nichrome" as an accepted answer. – Gaston
>   Jul 2 '18 at 19:48

The information is already there in the form of comments.  Stapling comments together and posting that as an answer duplicates information.  It doesn't contribute new knowledge.

Comment: Were you planning to keep the reputaion score?  Or, were you going to transfer it to the authors of the comments (somehow)?

Comment: I do not expect anyone to up vote those. Maybe someone will come up with an answer but these are answer and should not be in the comment. I listen to all the mods BTW.

Comment: You *did* expect to have your quoted answers upvoted.  It's that simple.

Comment: I am only trying to help answer old question. If you look at my Space.SE you will see that I give away all my rep. in bounties.

Comment: The information is already there in the forma of comments.  Stapling comments together and posting that as an answer duplicates information.  It doesn't contribute new knowledge.

Comment: Yes but it gets old question answer because they were in the comments. Don't worry I am informed and I will not copy and past answers anymore. I really want to be able to ask questions one day.

Comment: It's not plagiarism if he says who he's quoting (which he did in this case).

Comment: Some other SE sites encourage this kind of copying comments to answers, since it takes questions off the unanswered list and keeps them from being boosted by Community (assuming the answer gets accepted or a few upvotes).

Comment: @ThePhoton  I took that part out.

Comment: @ThePhoton  Some SE stacks might encourage this to improve their percentage of answered questions.  EE.SE has a high percentage of answered questions, thankfully.  We don't need to boost it artificially.

Answer (score 17):

There's a general rule across SE sites that if someone posts an answer as a comment, it's fair game to turn that into an answer.  I think there's even a blog post by Jeff Atwood (SE co-founder) saying it's fine.

However, the examples of what you did that Nick Alexeev posted are a terrible way to do it.  If you understand a question and answer well enough to turn the comment(s) into a full-blown answer, I'd say that's fine.  But simply copying a few different comments into the answer box isn't useful at all.  They might be components of a complete answer, but the examples are pretty much incoherent.

Comment: The important part being, whoever posted that as a comment likely didn't post it as an answer because they thought it needed to be further fleshed out to be answer-worthy. If you write an answer it needs to be better than the comments. And you don't need to give attribution or quote comment posters either, write something new, even if it contains the same technical info as posted comments.